# why isn't the programing working when i try to print (num % i)?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

```
num = 2

flag = False

if num == 1:
    print(num, "is not a prime number")
elif num > 1:
    # check for factors
    for i in range(2, num):
        test = num % i
        print(test)  # error not printing
        if (num % i) == 0: 
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        print(num, "is not a prime number")
    else:
        print(num, "is a prime number")
```

I have tried moving it inside the loop it still doesn't print and chat gpt shows it prints but my in my vs code it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `range` is exclusive. That is, if the value of `num` is `2`, then the program will not touch the the code within the `for`-loop. You could replace your loop with `for i in range(2, num + 1)`, but then the prime test will be invalid. Instead, choose a value for `number` greater than `2` to see the print on the screen.